# Constant Current Source Charger

Tags: current-limiting, constant-current, bms

I want to create a constant current charger of 3 A. The battery upper charge level is 54.6 V (battery is 6.6 Ah, 13S3P, 35 to 54.6 V, nominal 48 V).The input is 48 V, 6.6 A from a DC adapter. I plan to use a boost converter to step up the voltage to 54.6 V. Then the boost output would feed to CC input. I have referred https://www.instructables.com/Adding-a-Current-Limit-Feature-to-a-BuckBoost-Conv/,  https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/powerhouse/posts/how-to-design-a-simple-constant-current-constant-voltage-buck-converter, but I'm still not understanding how to create a constant current source. Also I don't want the circuits temps to be too high. Would like some help in this regard?
[image]

Comment: You need a buck-boost CC controller if your power source is 48 volts and your battery might be at 35 volts.

Comment: @Andyaka The buck boost would be for the load side. I want to implement a Boost circuit upto 54.6V.The 54.6V would be the CC Stage input voltage. I need help on how to design the CC stage for 3A constant current without overheating

Comment: Draw a block diagram because what you think you want and what I interpret from your words are different.

Comment: @Andyaka I have added a block diagram

Comment: Charging lithium batteries needs to be done with great care and presicion so they are not damaged. Based on the missing details of your block diagram, you should just buy a charger that can safely charge the batteries. Just having a CC-CV modes of operation is not enough for safe battery charging.

Comment: As I thought, of the battery is at 35 volts and the input at 48 volts you need buck functionality.

Comment: @Andyaka The battery nominal voltage is 48V,Upper value is 54.6V and lower value is 35V. So wont I need a buck-boost?

Comment: Read my first comment.

Comment: @Justme I have a fuel gauge and microcontroller. I need to setup the charging part

Comment: @Andyaka Haha ya my bad, so I thought of taking the buck-boost design from Texas Webench designer,https://webench.ti.com/power-designer/switching-regulator?powerSupply=0 , but there is no option for a constant current source creation. So I am thinking to create either a current limiter or current regulator circuit

Comment: The buck-boost can be made to act like a CC.

Comment: @Andyaka Is there any reference design I can follow to design the buck boost as a CV source

Comment: You need to properly fix up your original question in the light of our comments. This is a showcase Q and A site so, it's important you amend your question with what has been discussed in comments. Comments get deleted from time to time so, this is important. And I'm sure there is a reference design somewhere but, not in my head and, I don't want to go reading through the question and then comments again to figure out what is needed. This may sound harsh but, it's how this site works.